# django channels async consumer blocking on http request

Tags: django, aiohttp, django-channels

I have the following async consumer:

```
class MyAsyncSoncumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    
    async def send_http_request(self):

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
                timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=60)  # We have 60 seconds total timeout
        ) as session:
            await session.post('my_url', json={
                'key': 'value'
            })

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

        await self.send_http_request()

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        print(text_data)
```

Here, on connect method, I first accept the connection, then call a method that issues an http request with aiohttp, which has a 60 second timeout. Lets assume that the url we're sending the request to is inaccessible. My initial understanding is, as all these methods are coroutines, while we are waiting for the response to the request, if we receive a message, receive method would be called and we could process the message, before the request finishes. However, in reality, I only start receiveing messages after the request times out, so it seems like the consumer is waiting for the *send_http_request* to finish before being able to receive messages.

If I replace

```
await self.send_http_request()
```

with

```
asyncio.create_task(self.send_http_request())
```

I can reveive messages while the request is being made, as I do not await for it to finish on accept method.

My understanding was that in the first case also, while awaiting for the request, I would be able to receive messages as we are using different coroutines here, but that is not the case. Could it be that the whole consumer instance works as a single coroutine? Can someone clarify what's happenning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumers in django channels each run thier own runloop (async Task). But this is per consumer not per message, so if you are handling a message and you await something then the entire runloop for that websocket connection is awaiting.